# recovering an application that is not responding

Tags: crash, virtualdub

I'm running Windows XP and a program (virtualdub) that I've been working in has hung. It shows the message "...not responding". And it doesn't redraw etc.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to jumpstart a program that's hung like this. Perhaps doing a memory dump? Can memory dumps be "brought back to life" so to speak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't easily possible as it wouldn't just be the memory that would need to be "brought back to life", but also any handles to other devices/files would need to be recreated with the same value as the memory dump is expecting, not to mention the execution state of the application would also need to be restored.  If this was easily possible, bear in mind that the application is currently in a non-functioning state, so any restoration would only be able to restore it to it's currently non-functioning state.

You might also want to consider that the application may not have hung and is still processing. It may not be responding to the redraw (or other messages) from Windows and so windows is declaring it as "not responding". This usually occurs when the message handling thread is busy with other work.